# is there any solution while using TableParser in cucumber step if there is extra <td> added in HTML code so it mismatch the header and row data

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

`I used the TableParser here but in HTML there is extra <td> added in <tr> so it mismatch header and row data`your text`

so headers are  date, Stutus , FileName and RowsProcessed
but in status there are two  so it take filename=StatusVaue and RowProcessed=Filenamevalue and status=""
`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a helper class for verifying table rows which uses [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

```java
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Collector;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.select.Evaluator;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class HtmlTableWithHeader {
    private final Element headerRow;
    private final List<Element> bodyRows;
    private static final Set<String> CELL_TAGS = Set.of("td", "th");
    private static final Evaluator CELL_EVALUATOR = new Evaluator() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Element root, Element element) {
            return CELL_TAGS.contains(element.tagName());
        }
    };

    public static HtmlTableWithHeader parse(Element element) {
        if (!"table".equals(element.tagName())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported tag " + element.tagName());
        }
        Elements rows = element.getElementsByTag("tr");
        Iterator<Element> iterator = rows.iterator();
        Element headerRow = iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
        List<Element> bodyRows = new ArrayList<>();
        iterator.forEachRemaining(bodyRows::add);
        return new HtmlTableWithHeader(headerRow, bodyRows);
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getRowsAsListOfMaps() {
        if (headerRow == null || bodyRows.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<String> headerLabels = Collector.collect(CELL_EVALUATOR, headerRow).stream().map(Element::text).collect(toList());
        List<Map<String, String>> rowMaps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element bodyRow : bodyRows) {
            Elements cells = Collector.collect(CELL_EVALUATOR, bodyRow);
            Map<String, String> rowMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            IntStream.range(0, Math.min(headerLabels.size(), cells.size()))
                    .forEach(i -> rowMap.put(headerLabels.get(i), cells.get(i).text()));
            rowMaps.add(rowMap);
        }
        return rowMaps;
    }
}
```

Test case

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class HtmlTableWithHeaderTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetRowsAsListOfMaps() {
        // given
        String html =
                "<html>" +
                    "<table id='table-1'>" +
                        "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>" +
                        "<tr><td>Betty</td><td>21</td></tr>" +
                        "<tr><td>Barney</td><td>28</td></tr>" +
                    "</table>" +
                    "<table id='table-2'>" +
                        "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>" +
                        "<tr><td>Fred</td><td>20</td></tr>" +
                        "<tr><td>Wilma</td><td>25</td></tr>" +
                    "</table>" +
                "</html>";

        // when
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        HtmlTableWithHeader table = HtmlTableWithHeader.parse(doc.getElementById("table-2"));
        List<Map<String, String>> rows = table.getRowsAsListOfMaps();

        // then
        assertThat(rows).isEqualTo(List.of(
                Map.of("Name", "Fred", "Age", "20"),
                Map.of("Name", "Wilma", "Age", "25")
        ));
    }
}
```